# Typescript: fetch file from API and read it's original filename

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, blob, fetch

I'm trying to download some Excel file from the API that I've created in my react-typescript application using fetch method from tslib.
Here is the download code:

```
export const getBlobCors = url =>
  tryAjax<Blob>(
    () =>
      fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'omit',
        headers: new Headers({
          ...getAuthHeader(),
          responseType: 'blob'
        })
      }),
    async response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        const blob = await response.blob()
        return blob
      } else {
        throw new Error(DefaultErrorMsg)
      }
    }
  )
```

This method is being called from here:

```
async function downloadReport(urlData: ReportUrlData) {
  const url = reportUrl(urlData)
  const blob = await getBlobCors(url)
  const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.style.display = 'none'
  a.href = blobUrl
  a.download = 'Report.xlsx'
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a)
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl)
  })
}
```

As you can see for now the filename is hardcoded  `a.download = 'Report.xlsx'`, but what I need is to assign it to the filename that api has returned.
The file name does exist in the response header
[image: Response headers]
but when I', trying to read it `getBlobCors` method on response I'm getting `null` back, actually the `response.headers` is empty at all.

```
async response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        const fileName = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition') // null
        const headers = response.headers // Headers {}
        const blob = await response.blob()
        return blob
      }
```

Does anyone know how to read the file name from the response or any other I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost the whole day on it I've found the way to solve it. The problem was in my back-end. Because of the restriction in accessing response headers when using Fetch API over CORS, where by default access allowed only to a predefined list of standard headers like `Content-Type`, `Content-Language`, `Last-Modified`, `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and `Pragma`. Any other response headers need to be enabled on the server explicitly. In my case the back-end was ASP.NET Core , so I added custom CORS policy in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("WithExposedContentDispositionHeader", builder =>
{
     builder
     .AllowAnyOrigin()
     .WithExposedHeaders("content-disposition");
}));
```

And enabled this rule on the controller method

```
 [EnableCors("WithExposedContentDispositionHeader")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetExcelReport([FromQuery] ReportInput input) {...}
```